# Retrieve lost/damaged Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have an important excel file with a lot of data that cannot be opened because it was lost/corrupted. I have already tried most online tips as well as a few programs (stellar excel as well) but it appears as severely damaged. Previous version recovery and autorecover didn't work.

Comment: Restore from your backups. You don't have backups? You should do if you have important files.

Comment: hi, you say the file "cannot be opened because it was lost/corrupted". What does that mean? You haven't told us what happens when you try.

Comment: Additionally we need to know the specifics of each thing you have tried. Telling us you've tried most everything means we don't know what to suggest.

Comment: About how to repair **Repair a corrupted workbook**:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53